# why is my state not updating after axios request is resolved

Tags: reactjs, axios

Basically, I have defined a state called predictedCrop which is an array, however after the axios post request, I get back data from the backend and when I console.log that data, it shows however when I am setting the state nothing shows apart from an empty array.

This is the function

```
const [predictedCrop , setPredictedCrop] = useState([])


const getWeatherDetails = async() => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`)
            console.log(response.data)
            
            //Send temp and humidity to backend for analysis
            const dataToSend = response.data
            const sentWeatherData = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/analysis" , {
                data: dataToSend
            }).then((response) => {
                let dataObject = response.data;
                setPredictedCrop(dataObject)
                console.log(predictedCrop)
            })

        } catch {
            console.log("error")
        }
    }
```

I am certain that the data is reaching the frontend as when i console.log(data.response) I get the data back. I have also tried assigning a normal variable to it and console.log that variable and the data shows, It is only when I place it in the state that it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make the GET request when the page renders** . so use `the useEffect` hook to call your  function `getWeatherDetails`  when the  component mounts .

try it like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
   const getWeatherDetails = async() => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`)
            console.log(response.data)
            
            //Send temp and humidity to backend for analysis
            const dataToSend = response.data
            const sentWeatherData = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/analysis" , {
                data: dataToSend
            }).then((response) => {
                let dataObject = response.data;
                setPredictedCrop(dataObject)
                console.log(predictedCrop)
            })

        } catch {
            console.log("error")
        }
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: This causes an infinite loop of requests

Comment: Just  change   [predictedCrop ] dependency to empty erray like this [] . I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

`useState()` is asynchronous. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately. `useState()` does not always immediately update the component. Think of `useState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. So you can not see the result immediately inside the method.you can use useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(predictedCrop )
}, [predictedCrop ]);
```

Comment: This updated the predictedCrop however I got an infinite loop running to get the same request over and over again